# Como você resolveria essa simples questão?

Tags: python, funções, lista, range, números

Tava resolvendo uma simples questão de Python

O programa pede três números e retorna em ordem decrescente -

Resolvi fazer usando uma lista, assim:

```
numeros = []
for i in range(0,3):
    numeros.append(int(input('Digite um numero: : ')))
    numeros.sort()
    numeros.reverse()

print('a ordem eh:',numeros)
```

O programa funcionou, mas fiquei me perguntando  se essa resolução é 'aceitavél' aos olhos de um programador experiente. E se não, como fariam?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não precisa ordenar a lista a cada inserção de dados, pode fazer isso somente no final, pois os métodos `sort` e `reverse` trabalham com todos os dados da lista:

```
numeros = []

for i in range(0,3):
    numeros.append(int(input('Digite um numero: : ')))

numeros.sort()
numeros.reverse()

print('a ordem eh:',numeros)
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/DependableDopeyDecompiler

---

Também é possível fazer a ordenação da lista com apenas uma linha, utilizando o parâmetro `reverse` do método `sort`:

```
numeros = []

for i in range(0,3):
    numeros.append(int(input('Digite um numero: : ')))

numeros.sort(reverse=True)

print('a ordem eh:',numeros)
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/SwelteringAttractiveAttribute

---

Se você só precisa exibir a lista ordenada, também seria possível utilizar a função `sorted`, que diferente dos métodos utilizados, recebe uma lista e não altera a mesma, ela retorna uma nova lista ordenada:

```
numeros = []

for i in range(0,3):
    numeros.append(int(input('Digite um numero: : ')))

print('a ordem eh:',sorted(numeros, reverse=True))
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/VitalFrightenedApplicationsoftware

Comment: Valeuuu! ajudou muito

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma forma mais sucinta para se resolver esta questão, utilizando apenas **2** linhas de código. Para isso vamos precisar utilizar as funções **[sorted](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/dev/howto/sorting.html), [list](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) e [map](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/library/functions.html#map)**.

O script ficaria montado desta forma:

```
numeros = sorted(list(map(int, input('Digite todos os valores: ').split())), reverse=True)
print(f'\033[32ma ordem eh: {numeros}')
```

Observe que quando executamos este script recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite todos os valores:`. Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores da lista, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`.

A partir deste momento o algoritmo capturará todos os valores digitados, montará uma lista em ordem decrescente e, em seguida, exibirá a lista em ordem decrescente.